# Is it okay to install brick veneer directly to interior of a poured concrete foundation wall?

Tags: brick, masonry

Is it ok to install brick veneer directly to interior of a poured concrete foundation wall, or is there any additional preparation required?

Answer (score 2):

It won't hurt anything, but won't help you if your basement has problems. For example, if your basement is damp and cold, it will remain damp and cold after installation of the brick veneer. If this is the case, then I would recommend first insulating the walls with rigid insulation boards. It'll make your basement much more comfortable, cost you probably under $1,500, and there'll never be a better time than now!

Comment: In my case, I only have about 1 1/2" clearance between the concrete foundation and the side of the staircase, so I don't have the room to do much else besides apply the bricks directly.  The basement is dry so that is not an issue, especially along that wall.

Comment: there are fibre-cement fake brick panel products that you could put a little insulation behind.